# Question about uniqueness of solutions of Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I want to ask about the following theorem about uniqueness of solution of Dirichlet boundary problem to Laplace equation:

> Let $ \varOmega $ be a bounded domain with piecewise wmooth boundary, and let $ f\left(x\right):\overline{\varOmega}\to\mathbb{R} $ and $ \varphi\left(x\right):\partial\varOmega\to\mathbb{R} $ be continuous functions. Then, there exists at most one solution $ u\left(x\right)\in C^{2}\left(\overline{\varOmega},\mathbb{R}\right) $ to the Dirichlet boundary problem for the laplace equation $$ \begin{cases}
> \varDelta u\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right) & x\in\varOmega\\
> u\left(x\right)=\varphi\left(x\right) & \forall\partial\varOmega
> \end{cases} $$

That is the theorem as it stated in my lecture notes (also there is a proof, which I totally understand). But there is something I dont get.

Consider the Laplace equation where $ \varOmega = (0,L)\subset \mathbb{R} $ where $L>0 $, and $ f(x)= -\lambda\cdot u(x) $ where $\lambda >0 $.

Then $ \partial\varOmega=\left\{ 0,L\right\}  $, and assume $ u\left(0\right)=0,\thinspace\thinspace u\left(L\right)=0 $. (That is, $\varphi = 0 $).

So the problem is reduced to ordinary differential equation,and we know that $ \left\{ \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{L}x\right)\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty} $ are all eigenfunctions of the problem, and specifically, each eigenfunction solves the problem. So how does that fit with the uniquness of solution to the Dirichlet problem?

Comment: Your "$f(x) = -\lambda u(x)$" changes the problem considerably from the Laplace equation.

Comment: @A rural reader Why? The thorem only assumes $f$ is continuous, so why $f(x) =c \cdot u(x)$ is different?

Comment: Unique for a specified $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you consider the problem with $f(x)=\sin \pi x/L$. Then its unique solution with $\phi=0$ is $u(x)=-L^2f(x)/\pi^2$. There is no contradiction here, because neither $u=0$  or other (multiples of) eigenfunctions are solutions **with the same $f$** on the right hand side.